# jquery mutually exclusive click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 divs with 2 possible image tags for each (active or inactive). If one div is clicked to be active the other divs must be set to inactive. How do I accomplish this with img tags and what happens if user has javascript disable?

Comment: Could you clarify by adding example HTML to illustrate the situation?

Comment: the behavior would be same as the up/down voting here, but with a third arrow as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<div class="block" id="block1">
    <img src='inactive_block1.jpg'>
</div>

<div class="block" id="block2">
    <img src='inactive_block2.jpg'>
</div>

<div class="block" id="block3">
    <img src='inactive_block3.jpg'>
</div>
```

Using a library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), the javascript would look like:

```
$(function() {
    $('.block').click(function() {
       $('#block1').find('img').attr('src', 'inactive_block1.jpg');
       $('#block2').find('img').attr('src', 'inactive_block2.jpg');
       $('#block3').find('img').attr('src', 'inactive_block3.jpg');
       $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'active_' + $(this).attr('id') + '.jpg');
    });
});
```

With the above, if you have `inactive_block1.jpg`, `inactive_block2.jpg`, `inactive_block3.jpg` and `active_block1.jpg`, `active_block2.jpg` and `active_block3.jpg` you should get what you want.

It's up to you whether its worth it or not to have javascript disabled fallbacks, mostly depending on whether you expect a large amount of your audience to have javascript disabled.

Comment: within each div i want there to be an img tag, not a css background.

Comment: thanks, but one other twist... the inactive and active jpg are not the same in each div..

Comment: Oops. I had a couple of errors in it. Fixed it. Try it now. Both the html and the javascript changed, so yeah.

Answer (score 1):

if a user has JavaScript disabled, there is nothing you can do that is JavaScript-based to deal with dynamically modifying the page. The only other option you have is to create a "deprecated" version of your functionality that requires a page request after each click.

I would recommend researching how to dynamically add/remove classes from elements in the DOM, that is how I would approach this problem. You could easily do a jQuery select for all elements who are "active" on click and set a "disabled" class on them, that way you are essentially blacking out everything except the element you've clicked.

Does that make sense?

Comment: so i would put all both active and inactive image tags in html. and add  remove classes to disable them? Or so as above and specify src when they are clicked?